# Money.js + LocalStorage rates

Tags: javascript, html, intel-xdk, money.js

I'm using Intel XDK to make a conversion tool, my script detects if the device has internet connection, if YES use this to get the latest rate from openexchangerates via JSON and storage it in localstorage:

```
$.getJSON('https://openexchangerates.org/api/latest.json?app_id=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',function(data) {
                    var localData = JSON.stringify(data);
                    localStorage.setItem('convrates', localData);
                    // Check money.js has finished loading:
                    if ( typeof fx !== "undefined" && fx.rates ) {
                        fx.rates = data.rates;
                        fx.base = data.base;
                    } else {
                        // If not, apply to fxSetup global:
                        var fxSetup = {
                            rates : data.rates,
                            base : data.base
                        }
                    }
                });
```

This is ok! But when try to get this info from localstorage, nothing happens...

```
var localData = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('convrates'));
            $.getJSON(localData,function(data) {
                    // Check money.js has finished loading:
                    if ( typeof fx !== "undefined" && fx.rates ) {
                        fx.rates = data.rates;
                        fx.base = data.base;
                    } else {
                        // If not, apply to fxSetup global:
                        var fxSetup = {
                            rates : data.rates,
                            base : data.base
                        }
                    }
             });
```

This is the JSON data exemple:

```
{
 "disclaimer": "Exchange rates are provided for informational purposes only, and do not constitute financial advice of any kind. Although every attempt is made to ensure quality, NO guarantees are given whatsoever of accuracy, validity, availability, or fitness for any purpose - please use at your own risk. All usage is subject to your acceptance of the Terms and Conditions of Service, available at: https://openexchangerates.org/terms/",
 "license": "Data sourced from various providers with public-facing APIs; copyright may apply; resale is prohibited; no warranties given of any kind. Bitcoin data provided by http://coindesk.com. All usage is subject to your acceptance of the License Agreement available at: https://openexchangerates.org/license/",
"timestamp": 1417507252,
"base": "USD",
"rates": {
"AED": 3.673268,
"AFN": 57.871426,
"ALL": 112.5408,
"AMD": 439.297503,
"ANG": 1.7891,
"AOA": 101.106125,
"ARS": 8.531535,
"AUD": 1.174523,
"AWG": 1.79,
"AZN": 0.783933,
"BAM": 1.570651,
"BBD": 2,
"BDT": 77.73667,
}
}
```

I really don't know how to make it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it works:

Load from LocalStorage

```
var data = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('convrates'));

            $.each(data, function(key, value){
               // alert(key + ' = ' + value);
                    // Check money.js has finished loading:
                    if ( typeof fx !== "undefined" && fx.rates ) {
                        fx.rates = data.rates;
                        fx.base = data.base;
                    } else {
                        // If not, apply to fxSetup global:
                        var fxSetup = {
                            rates : data.rates,
                            base : data.base
                        }
                    }
             });
```

Save in LocalStorage

```
 $.getJSON('https://openexchangerates.org/api/latest.json?app_id=3f098d62737c416c9e23ec9dc5e8b426',function(data) {
                    localStorage.setItem('convrates', JSON.stringify(data));
                    // Check money.js has finished loading:
                    if ( typeof fx !== "undefined" && fx.rates ) {
                        fx.rates = data.rates;
                        fx.base = data.base;
                    } else {
                        // If not, apply to fxSetup global:
                        var fxSetup = {
                            rates : data.rates,
                            base : data.base
                        }
                    }
                });
```

Answer (score 1):

You can treat localStorage kind of like normal JS object, so first off you don't need to stringify and parse the JS object.  Instead of writing

```
var localData = JSON.stringify(data);
localStorage.setItem('convrates', localData);
```

you can just do

```
localStorage['convrates'] = data;
```

or even

```
localStorage.convrates = data;
```

To retrieve the data, you may still want to use `getItem()`, as this will return null rather than throw an error if `convrates` doesn't exist, so to retrieve the data again you just do

```
data = localStorage.getItem('convrates');
```

which will leave `data` either `null` or with the `convrates` object most recently stored there.

Calling `$.getJSON` on `localData` doesn't really make sense, as that's a JS object, not a URL.